# Apache mod_rewrite domain to subdomain?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have this address http://www.example.com and have this page http://www.example.com/world.
Can I do this with mod_rewrite,to my page become http://world.example.com ?
Any link,tutorial,...,will be nice,if I can do this?
And what will be with these links for example:

```
  http://www.example.com/world/some-other-page
  http://www.example.com/world/and-second-apge
```

will these links also be rewritten to  :

```
 http://world.example.com/some-other-page
 http://world.example.com/and-second-apge
```

Another question,is this good for SEO ?

I'm sorry on my bad English.

Comment: Try adding the following to `.htaccess` in the parent directory above the directory of interest: `RedirectMatch ^/foo/$ /foo/bar/` or `RedirectMatch ^/foo/$ /bar/baz/`. Also see [How to get apache2 to redirect to a subdirectory](http://serverfault.com/q/9992/145545).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^world/([a-z0-9\-_\.]+)/?(.*)$ http://$1.domain.com/$2 [QSA,NC,R,L]
```

so:

```
http://www.domain.com/world/page => http://world.domain.com/page
```

Comment: Hi,tnx for response,will try this,and let you know is it working.

Comment: Shouldn't you escape the dot in the condition: `^domain\.com`? Also, should it always use `http` in the rewrite rule: `http://www.domain.com/$1`?