# mod_rewrite append subdomain to URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I'm looking to append a subdomain of "archives" to URLs that are clicked to allow them to go the new archives site, instead of the regular site. You can visit the site at http://archives.thegatepost.com and get a feel for what I'm looking to do.

1. User visits site at: #http://archives.thegatepost.com/archived06.html
2. User clicks link to view: #http://www.thegatepost.com/news/GP_pgs1-4.pdf
3. Re-written to: #http://archives.thegatepost.com/news/GP_pgs1-4.pdf

   - This needs to be able to be accomplished in a .htaccess file
   - Not worried about 301 or anything like that. If it can be done SEO friendly, all the better, if not no loss.

I have tried [Apache mod_rewrite domain to subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898964/apache-mod-rewrite-domain-to-subdomain), and it's not working:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^thegatepost.com/archives [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.thegatepost.com/archives/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thegatepost\archives\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^archives/([a-z0-9\-_\.]+)/?(.*)$ http://$1.thegatepost.com/archives/$2 [QSA,NC,R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the .htaccess file in the root folder of the `www.thegatepost.com` domain

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if request on www.gatepost.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thegatepost\.com$ [NC]
#and for a resource in the /news/ directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news/ [NC]
#redirect them to same resource on the archives.thegatepost.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://archives.thegatepost.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```